# Django. Как убрать браузерные предупреждения о неверном вводе пароля/почты и т.д

Tags: python, django, браузер

У меня есть форма с полями. Если данные введены неверно - выскакивают подсказки. Как я выяснил это браузерная ошибка никак не связанная с Django. Вопрос: как их убрать? В разных браузерах они отображаются по-разному. Прикладываю скриншоты

Opera GX:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Firefox:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В HTML в тэге **form** необходимо добавить атрибуты: *action="" и novalidate*

```
<!--Register-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container_for_form">
            <p id="reg">Регистрация</p>
            <form method="POST" action="" novalidate>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <input type=submit id=submit value=Зарегистрироваться>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```